# How to trigger keyReleased event in java swing

Tags: java, swing, events, keylistener, jtextcomponent

i am trying to trigger key released event in java swing.

```
txtEmailId.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            // override keyReleased listener on the Email TextField
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                                System.out.println("ok");
            }
        });
```

above code running successfully now i want to call this keyReleased event after `txtEmailId.setText("hello");` manually how it is possible?

Comment: you means how to trigger the keyReleased by code manually?

Comment: yes ,how it is possible?

Comment: You cannot call keyReleased programatically, please check [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent))

Comment: Then how i can solve my problem? is there any way?

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them. 2) This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: Use a DocumentListener as it will be noticed when setText is called, when the user types someone or text is pasted into te field, won't suffer from possible mutation exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `KeyAdapter` use [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html). Try next example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JTextField f = new JTextField();
        f.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                validate(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                validate(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                validate(e);
            }

            private void validate(DocumentEvent e) {
                try {
                    String text = e.getDocument().getText(0, e.getDocument().getLength());
                    if(text.equals("hello")){
                        System.out.println("ok");
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        f.setText("hello");
        add(f);
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: how this is meet with my question?

Comment: I suggest you another way for triggering event on your `JTextField` without fire events manually.

Comment: @user3363563 It is not-recommended to use a KeyListener of text components as the events could be consumed before they reach your listener or cause mutation errors if you try and modify the field during the key event notification, it also does not take into account when text is lasted into the field. DocumentListener is the recommended  ethos for monitoring changes to fields/documents content and DocumentFilter for filtering content before its committed to the document/field

Comment: @user3363563 This solution solves your problem directly as it will be notified when setText is called, all round, it's an excellent solution for your problem as it overcomes a number of issues you're not having yet and the problem you are having and dose not deserve a vote down. +1

Comment: Well, since it seems like you asked an XY problem, it seems this answer was trying to guess the point of what you are doing, and provide an altogether better approach to it.  It doesn't take much experience to know that anything that mixes Swing and `KeyListener` has a better solution, but it is hard to know what the best solution is, until you state what you are trying to *achieve* (as opposed to what you are trying to *do*).

Comment: ok now? it's my mistake because i am beginner in java i have accept your answer now